# How to add images to rock, paper scissors game

Tags: javascript, image

I want to add some images to my game. When you click the button, it should come up with a image. Would some please advise me or show me how can I do that?

My HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<H1>Rock Paper Scissors</H1>
<H2>Instructions</H2>
<p>Click a button to choose what to throw</p>
<p id="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="Rock" onclick="hand(0);" />
    <input type="button" value="Paper" onclick="hand(1);" />
    <input type="button" value="Scissors" onclick="hand(2);" /> 
</p>
<h3>Scoreboard:</h3>
<ul id="scoreboard">
        Wins: <span id="win">0</span>
    <br/>
        Losses: <span id="lose">0</span>
    <br/>
        Ties: <span id="tie">0</span>      
</ul>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var ties = 0;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;

// randInt returns a random integer between 0 and 2
function randInt() {return Math.floor(Math.random()*3);}

  function msgAlert(msg, player, comp) {
var outcome = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

if (msg === "tie") {
    alert("Tie!\n" + "Player: " + outcome[player] + "\n" + "Computer: " + outcome[comp]);
}

if (msg === "win") {
    alert("You won!\n" + "Player: " + outcome[player] + "\n" + "Computer: " + outcome[comp]);
}          

if (msg === "lose") {
    alert("You lost!\n" + "Player: " + outcome[player] + "\n" + "Computer: " + outcome[comp]);
}
}

function updateScore(result) {
var tie = document.getElementById("tie");
var win = document.getElementById("win");
var lose = document.getElementById("lose");

if (result === "tie") {
    ties++;
    tie.innerHTML = ties;
}

if (result === "win") {
    wins++;
    win.innerHTML = wins;
}

if (result === "lose") {
    losses++;
    lose.innerHTML = losses;
}
}

function hand(player) {
var comp = randInt();

if (player === comp) {
    updateScore("tie");
    msgAlert("tie", player, comp);
}

/* Rock Conditions */
if (player === 0 && comp === 1) {
    updateScore("lose");
    msgAlert("lose", player, comp);
}

if (player === 0 && comp === 2) {
    updateScore("win");
    msgAlert("win", player, comp);
}

/* Paper Conditions */
if (player === 1 && comp === 0) {
    updateScore("win");
    msgAlert("win", player, comp);
}

if (player === 1 && comp === 2) {
    updateScore("lose");
    msgAlert("lose", player, comp);
}

/* Scissors Conditions */
if (player === 2 && comp === 0) {
    updateScore("lose");
    msgAlert("lose", player, comp);
}

if (player === 2 && comp === 1) {
    updateScore("win");
    msgAlert("win", player, comp);
}
}
```

This is my Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Matt1990/o6ac51v0/1/

Comment: Be specific - do you want to know how to add images to `html` through `javascript`? There's plenty of resources online. If you want some _specific_ way to use images, tell us. If you expect people to write code for you, it won't happen. This is a Q&A site for specific technical issues - we won't write code for you or try to figure out _what_ your problem is without any clues. This is too broad as it is.

Comment: I have some images that i would like to put into my game. I was just wondering how can i add them so i put them in so when the player is playing the game they click rock paper or scissors and then the button they click it will come up with the image of the button that they clicked

Comment: i dont want people to write code for me by the way @ivy_lynx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getElementByClass and onClick to set up a listener function.
Something like:

```
getElementByClass('.button').onClick = function(){

}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick

Then within the anonymous function you can write some code to make the image appear where you want it. You can use something like .appendChild

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild

There is a nice example in the .appendChild link that posted above. Hope it helps.

Edit: You can also investigate jQuery which can make this sort of DOM manipulation a bit easier once you get a feel for it.